# how do I create a switch statement to play audio from a char array?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a switch statement to assign different audio files to statements inputted into the keyboard, which are received by the char array.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keybutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText keyInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key);
    String notes = keyInput.getText().toString();
    char[] charArray;
    for (char c : charArray = notes.toCharArray()) {
```

I Need HELP RIGHT HERE

```
switch ((Boolean) View.()) {/*what do i  do here?()) {
            case: 
                /*that a certain key is pressed

                 */
```

AND HERE

```
MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sample1);
                mp1.start();
                break;
            /* above (and/or others) happens on button click
             */

    }
    ;

    }
    ;
```

help?

Comment: Instead of a switch with strings you could get the Ascii int value for each character and make your switch statement with them.

Comment: @AlexandreBOURETZ not a dupe.

Comment: @AlexandreBOURETZ how do I do that?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Put the characters (as a string) after `case`

Comment: And what is `switch ((Boolean) View.())`?? Don't you want something like `switch c`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I dont know how to write the switch statement

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is the char array, don't use a char array

```
String notes = keyInput.getText().toString();
for (int i = 0: i < notes.length(); i++) {
    String c = ""+notes.charAt(i);
    switch (c.toLowerCase()) {
        case "a":
            // play the note 
            break;
    } 
}
```

**Other solutions without a switch**

1) You can have a `Map<Character, Integer>` to store a (character, song) pairing, which is cleaner code than a massive switch statement

```
map.put('a', R.raw.note_a); // Name your resources based on the notes

...

char noteChar = 'a'; // For example
Integer note = map.get(noteChar);
if (note != null) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, note);
    mp.start();
}
```

2) You can use dynamic resource lookups

```
// This returns 'R.raw.note_a', for example
int note = getResources().getIdentifier("note_"+noteChar, "raw", getPackageName()); 

if (resourceID != 0) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, note);
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: I reread this and i'm not sure this will work. based on user input, I want to create a "song" that the user "creates" based on what they put in. I want it to play on a button click. I have tried many things, with no success. I think the char array will work. I just do not know how to map it out and create a switch. I think I have to use a hash map? Can you help me in this regard? Much thanks! David

Comment: Why won't this answer work? Did you try it? I don't know what notes you have, so you'll have to add the `case` statements yourself. A map is not necessary, only "cleaner"

Comment: I want my case statement to include every note in the pentatonic scale. so I want it to play after the fact, based on the user input. I don't know how to write the case statement. I need in fact multiple mediaplayers to play a key that was pressed after the fact.

Comment: Learn to write a case statement, then. I don't understand your hesitance to at least try to research how

Comment: I've also clearly provided two alternatives that don't even require case statements

Comment: im just having trouble. which is the reason why I posted it on stackoverflow. I'm trying to write your code but im getting errors.

Comment: It's fine that you asked here, but you'll want to be  more specific than "there's errors" or "it's not working". Try to understand, we're not running your code, this is the very first time we're seeing it. Try to write your posts as such

Comment: String notes = keyInput.getText().toString();
for (int i = 0: i < notes.length(); i++) {
    String c = ""+notes.charAt(i);
    switch (c) {                                         it cant find notes.length

Comment: I don't know what you mean... I think my code is correct.  That's a method, though, not a property. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_length.htm Maybe try learning more about Java before attempting Android?